# Is it possible to count only the total replies message via IMAP()

Tags: php, imap, reply

I'm working on the 1st imap() project. I want to count every message type - unread, read, reply and deleted. Only the "reply" status that consumes me a lot of time. I tried to search here and google. But no luck. Some says I need to create my own way to count it coz there's no such a universal function for it.

So may I have you guys a suggestion on how to count it. Or point me the way to do so. (I don't ask for a complete code. Just only suggestions.)

Regards,

Comment: Total replies message via IMAP() as in? Sent messages?

Comment: yest, in sent messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may look into [**imap_search**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-search.php)

```
 $sentfolder = "{".$host."}".'SENT'; //sent folder name
 $outbox = imap_open($sentfolder,$username ,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Mail: ' . imap_last_error());
 $sent_msgs = imap_search($outbox, 'ALL');
```

**OR:**

```
 // match messages with the \\ANSWERED flag set
$sent_msgs = imap_search($outbox, 'ANSWERED');
```

Comment: I did this :

$sentbox=imap_open("{mail.myurl.com:143/novalidate-cert}SENT", "$imap_user" , "$imap_pw");

$ans=imap_search($sentbox, "ANSWERED"); 

echo $ans;

But there's nothing happens. Or I need to give it a flag first?

Comment: Isn't it the standard name for every mailbox. To be honest - I don't know. Let me ask my hosting first. Or could you give me a clue of the possible name please?

Comment: It's `[Gmail]/Sent Mail` for Gmail, use `$outbox = imap_open($sentfolder,$username ,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Mail: ' . imap_last_error());` to know if there is an error connecting to mailbox

Comment: I've tried "die" but there's no error comes after. What the problem should be then?

Comment: Still nothing for "}SENT" but when I changed it into "}INBOX" it returns "Array". Be advice please.

Comment: Use `print_r($ans);` for array and i guess it's the sent folder name that you want and you have your problem solved :)

Comment: Again, nothing for "}SENT" but got as many arrays as the total message number (Nmsgs) when I changed it to "}INBOX". What if the sent box name incorrect? What the error should be?

Comment: Yes there is an error here:  `$sentfolder = "{".$host."}".'your_folder_name';`

Comment: Okey, I'm waiting for my hosting reply. They'll give me all mailbox's name. So it would solve the problem. Thank you very much for your time. Please keep in touch for my code to be enlighten. :)

Comment: @Wilf : Thanks, pleas upvote/accept...cheers and here to help :)

Comment: Is there anything greater than "accept"? Thank you very much. You're so kind. :)

Comment: Aditya, your solution is work great! I've got my answer from my hosting. It's simple as example#1 here -> http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-list.php. Together with your codes. It works like a charm.